# jupyter nbconvert doesn't save file for matplotlib.savefig

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to save a png file using pyplot.savefig function. Works fine when run via jupyter web UI. But when I run it via command line, it doesn't create the image.

Command line: `jupyter nbconvert FILE_NAME.ipynb`

code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# evenly sampled time at 200ms intervals
t = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)

# red dashes, blue squares and green triangles
plt.plot(t, t, 'r--', t, t**2, 'bs', t, t**3, 'g^')

plt.savefig('test-image-2.png', format='png', dpi=1200)

plt.show()
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your command to:

`jupyter nbconvert FILE_NAME.ipynb --execute`

Otherwise, well, none of the cells are executed.

This is stated in the docs shown with `jupyter nbconvert --help`:

```
$ jupyter nbconvert --help
This application is used to convert notebook files (*.ipynb) to various other
formats.

WARNING: THE COMMANDLINE INTERFACE MAY CHANGE IN FUTURE RELEASES.

Options
-------

Arguments that take values are actually convenience aliases to full
Configurables, whose aliases are listed on the help line. For more information
on full configurables, see '--help-all'.

--debug
    set log level to logging.DEBUG (maximize logging output)
--generate-config
    generate default config file
-y
    Answer yes to any questions instead of prompting.
--execute
    Execute the notebook prior to export.
[snip]
```